# Does puppet have a path variable

Tags: puppet

I was looking at a puppet manifest and saw this

```
exec { "my_command":
    command => "do some command",
    path => "$::path",
}
```

I don't see the variable path being set anywhere though in the manifest file. Is "$::path" a special variable in puppet?

When I tried an example command of `grep` with no path, it couldn't be found, but when I had `"$::path"` it worked just ifne.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a special variable. More precisely, it's a **fact**. You can always refer to facts like top-scope variables (`$::name`).

More info here:

https://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/variables.html#facts

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the facts about a system. You can type "facter" in your terminal where you have installed puppet. It will give you the entire facts about a the said system. You can check out particular fact by typing the following in the terminal

```
    facter path
```

This fact can be referenced as variables in puppet manifest by using

```
    $::path
```